# Placing plots around a circle with SectorChart

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I need to position some graphs around a circle so that each occupies a sector. There're 18 graphs in total and the first five are shown below:

```
AllData=Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/DsVfiMZN","Table"];
datai=Table[data[20*i]=AllData[[All,2*i+1;;2*i+2]],{i,0,17}];
ploti=Table[p[20*i]=ListLinePlot[data[20*i],PlotRange->All,Axes->False,PlotStyle->{Black}],{i,0,4}];
GraphicsRow[ploti,ImageSize->1000]
```

[image]

The code for the SectorChart approach to place the graphs around a circle is:

```
AllData=Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/DsVfiMZN","Table"];
columns=Range@36;angles=Partition[Subdivide[0,2Pi,Length[columns]/2],2,1];
rescaled=AllData[[All,#]]&/@Partition[columns,2];
rescaled[[All,All,1]]=MapIndexed[Rescale[#,MinMax[AllData[[All,1]]],angles[[#2[[1]]]]]&,rescaled[[All,All,1]]];
cEF={Line[MapThread[# {Cos@#2,Sin@#2}&,{#[[2,1]]+#3[[1]],Subdivide[#[[1,1]],#[[1,2]],Length[#3[[1]]]-1]}]],FaceForm[],ChartElementData["Sector"][{#[[1]],{#[[2,1]],#[[2,2]]}},##2]}&;
yvals=rescaled[[All,All,-1]];
SectorChart[{1,Max@yvals}->#&/@yvals,SectorOrigin->{{5Pi/9,"Clockwise"},2},ImageSize->500,ChartStyle->Black,ChartElementFunction->cEF]
```

[image]

The graphs are placed around the circle starting from the 12 o'clock position. However, I've noticed that they are flipped horizontally from the original graphs. The graph at the 12 o'clock position looks like the mirror image of the first one of the five shown above and I can't figure out why.

Comment: try replacing `Subdivide[...]` in `cEF` with `Reverse @ Subdivide[...]`?